# youtube thumbnail using paused videos

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to make a web-app in which people can remix youtube videos...

I looked at the youtube api, and it doesn't seem to support thumbnail at a specific location.

So, I'm trying to create multiple chromeless youtube videos, start them at specific positions and stop them almost immediately to make them seem like "thumbnails".

However, the videos all show up black when I try to do so.
Here's the link to the source code: http://pastebin.com/6Bpr1Dsz

Note that when I comment out the pauseVideo part, the videos play fine.
ps: I tried to make this work on jsfiddle, but it wouldn't work.

Thanks :)